# Adding or removing Strings in a ListView

Tags: java, android, string, listview

I'm making an app in which when you press a botton, it choose a random number and depending on that number shows a different text.

Here is the `onClick` method in the file **"Escoger.java"**, which corresponds to a xml file with a `Button` and some `TextViews`:

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);

    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.btnEscoger:

        tvTIngredientes.setText(R.string.Title_Ingredientes);
        tvTExplicacion.setText(R.string.Title_Explicacion);

        Random r=new Random();
        plato = r.nextInt(4-1);

        if(plato==1){
            tvTituloComida.setText(R.string.Comida1);
            tvIngredientes.setText(R.string.Ingredientes1);
            tvExplicacion.setText(R.string.Explicacion1); }
        if(plato==2){
            tvTituloComida.setText(R.string.Comida2);
            tvIngredientes.setText(R.string.Ingredientes2);
            tvExplicacion.setText(R.string.Explicacion2); }
        if(plato==3){
            tvTituloComida.setText(R.string.Comida3);
            tvIngredientes.setText(R.string.Ingredientes3);
            tvExplicacion.setText(R.string.Explicacion3); }
        if(plato==4){
            tvTituloComida.setText(R.string.Comida4);
            tvIngredientes.setText(R.string.Ingredientes4);
            tvExplicacion.setText(R.string.Explicacion4); }
        break;

    case R.id.btnSettings:
        d.setTitle(R.string.Setting_Title);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.preferencias);
        d.show();
        break;
    }
}
```

I've made a xml file with a `ListView`, and here is its java file, **"Historia.java"**.

```
package org.example.whatsfordinner;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class Historia extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.historia);

    String[] names = new String[]{"Linux", "Android", "Windows"};
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));

}
}
```

If I run this, it appears a `ListView` with the items **"Linux"**, **"Android"** and **"Windows"**, because this file I did following a tutorial.

What I want is to change **"Linux"**, **"Android"** and **"Windows"** by the chosen name `(R.string.Comida#)` emerged of the `random()`;, and with infinite items, not only three.

Can you tell me the code I have to use, please? (I'm very new at **Android** programming).

Thank you very much!

Comment: getString(R.string.comida) will return the string resource.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Strings to the adapter and notify the ListView that the underlying data has changed. I suggest that you check out [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make  define a string just below your Historia  class  ( in **C++** u call that global variable )
Then simply change any pre-existing element with your new element which depends on random numbers ...

Also note do use  `onSavedInstancestat()` function to save data and use restore in `onCreate()` whenever ur activity restarts .......

Your activity restarts because orientation change .... you have to use any other app ... then come resume this app

Comment: sorry, but I'm learning Android programming and I don't know how to do the first part of your answer... (change any pre-existing element with your new element which depends on random numbers ...) Can you help me, please?